# What may and don't I may do in FormCreate()?

Tags: delphi

I think this must be a FAQ, but googling hasn't really helped.

What may I do - and may do not - in `FormCreate()`?

I am wondering if all of the form's child controls are fully created and available for access, etc.

The reason I ask is that I stumbled over an old project where my `FormCreate()` simply consists of

```
Sleep(1000);  
PostMessage(Handle, UM_PROGRAM_START, 0, 0);
```

It seems that I want to "wait a bit" and then do some initialization "when things have settled down" ...

Surely I had a reason for it at the time(?), but, in the absence of an enlightening comment I am unable to recall why I felt that to be necessary.

Can anyone state, or reference a link which states, any restrictions on what one may do in `FormCreate()`?

---

[Update] I think thta DavidHefferman found the solution when he wrote "the application starts pumping messages. That happens when you call Application.Run in your .dpr file".

I guess that I wasn't concerned about a single form. For instance, my main form wants to do somethign with my config/options form at start up, so obviously would have to wait until it is created.

Here's a typical .DPR from one of my projects ...

```
Application.Initialize;
Application.CreateForm(TGlobal, Global);
Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
Application.CreateForm(TMainForm, MainForm);

Application.CreateForm(TLoginForm, LoginForm);
Application.CreateForm(TConfigurationForm, ConfigurationForm);

//[snip] a bunch of other forms ...

Application.Run();
```

So, it makes sense for my app's `mainForm.CreateForm()` to send a `UM_APPLICATION_START` to itself which it won't process until all forms are created & initialized (or, I could just call the fn() which the message triggers from my .DPR after `Application.Run()` is called; but I prefer the message as it is more obvious - I rarely look at my .DPR files).

Comment: take a look at what you do when the UM_PROGRAM_START arrives, that will bring the reason to your mind.

Comment: OnCreate will be fired after the Creation of the ChildComponents. But depending on OldCreateOrder it will be fired inside Create or AfterConstruction. But some Controls can also use a PostMessage, to perform their final Initialization, and for that they cannot be used in OnCreate Event. And for that reason you may have choosen to post a Message - yes, forget about the sleep :o)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/382527/delphi-app-initialization-best-practices-approach

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075839/how-do-do-things-during-delphi-form-startup/2095224

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no definitive documentation giving the list of all the things you can do and connot do in a form's OnCreate.

As for whether or not the .dfm file has been processed and all the form's owned components created, yes they have.

I wouldn't place much store in the code you have found. Calling Sleep during start up, to make the main thread wait, is absolutely not good practice. If the code wanted to wait for another thread it could block for that thread, or wait to get a message from that thread. This just looks like code that got put in by someone who didn't understand what he/she was doing. And the code never got removed.

The other line of code is reasonable:

```
PostMessage(Handle, UM_PROGRAM_START, 0, 0);
```

Because this message is posted, it won't get processed until the application starts pumping messages. That happens when you call Application.Run in your .dpr file. Which means that everything related to the creation of you main form happens before that message is pulled off the queue.

Comment: +1 :"And I know, because ... I was that coder" (with apologies to Max Bygraves, which ought to phase our colonial cousins ;-)  Yup, I agree, I can skip the `sleep()` (and often do), but why did I feel the need to call `PostMessage()` ?

Comment: When a window gets created it gets sent lots of messages. Sent as in SendMessage deliver synchronously. The PostMessage invokes an action that will fire after the main window has finished all of its initialization. Maybe that's why you did it. Hard to be 100% sure. What does your app do in response to that message?

Comment: +1 All of the initialization stuff you might expect in `FormCreate()`

Comment: Used this way for as long as I can remember. I thought there may've been something added to Delphi by now. Currently migrating old code to Delphi 12 that got broken as a result of TCustomForm.Create no longer calling DoCreate which is setting Visible to True, so code that does things like SetFocus in Create/OnCreate errors. For years I wondered why there isn't an event that fires once, like OnCreate but where you can assume all initialisation events have been called, but the form is still not showing, and now you can set the UI up and call the likes of SetFocus. PostMessage it still is then.

Comment: Worth noting: if you want to use this as a way to run TForm's OnShow code only once (e.g. to call SomeTextBox.SetFocus in it), then you are making an assumption your form is indeed Visible (i.e. this line in Vcl.Forms must set Visible to True: if fsVisible in FFormState then Visible := True)

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't put to much initialization code in FormCreate, instead I would place it into a separate function, like

```
fm := TForm.Create;
fm.Init;
```

The problem is, an exception thrown in the FormCreate() procedure is not re-thrown (there is only a MessageBox). That means, your code keeps running, although the form is not initialized correctly.

Comment: The `Init` stuff is probably what is called by the `PostMessage()` action.

Comment: +1 LURD Max, I presume that you are calling `fm.Init` from `<project>.dpr`? Seems similar to sending a message - any subtle differences? Not sure about the exception bit - do you want to add 'try ... except` to your otherwise empty `FornmCreate`?

Comment: I am not a fan of events or messages. They are always more complex to debug. You need to know who has invoked it and where does it come from. If you just call a function, you exactly know where it is called (when you just look at the source code).

Comment: ...

Not sure what code you want to invoke in your Init function. When you have to access external resources like a DB, then load it into a seperate object first, and use the object instead of accessing the resource directly.

In my case I use a global TConfig singleton object, which loads the data on startup and is accessible in all forms.

Answer (score 2):

You may do whatever you want in the FormCreate. But there is no message handler to play with, that's all. In general I would create dependent objects in the FormCreate and free them in the FormDestroy. I would also try to avoid time consuming initialization routines.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by, "there's no message handler"?

Comment: Sorry, my statement was unclear. During a FormCreate of the main form, the message handler of the application is not yet initialized. I know this problem ('what to do in a FormCreate') from questioning how to initialize an application using the MainForm.FormCreate.

Comment: The message pump hasn't started sure. But messages can be posted. And synchronous messages are still delivered direct to window proc.